# Как лучше реализовать сетку из окон на php

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Страница разделена на 2 горизонтальные области. Левая (рабочая зона) содержит область (четырехугольник), внутри которой произвольно располагаются n-ое кол-во меньших по размеру четырехугольников (блоков). Правая часть (меню элементов) содержит список текстовых элементов для отображения.
Пользователь может выбрать текст для отображения щелкнув по нему и задать область отображения. В случае, если выделенная область не выходит за рамки 1 блока, текст необходимо отобразить в точности в той зоне, которая была выделена. Если выделенная зона охватывает несколько блоков, то текст автоматически занимает их целиком (если они пусты). После добавления текста необходимо иметь возможность изменять размер, занимаемой области (масштабировать). Область, занимаемая текстом, должна быть подобием контейнера, с которым в последствии можно работать (дополнять, к примеру).
Как лучше организовать такую структуру на php странице? Какие использовать библиотеки, буду рад любой идее.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По большей части интересуют готовые решения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extjs - сложно, мощно. Да, она платная, но если внимательно поковырять сайт, есть там бесплатная версия для опенсорсных проектов.
Зато это как раз то, что нужно, почти идеальное готовое решение.

Чуть сложнее - освоить всевозможные структурные фреймворки, вроде Backbone.js, angular. Но там придется рисовать окна самостоятельно, хотя связь между ними на 80% будет уже реализована.

Если интересуют серверные решения, то там почти любой шаблонизатор или фреймворк допускает разделение на вьюхи, которые можно уже запихнуть в сетку из дивов. Посмотрите yii/yii2/symfony

Comment: Малыми жертвами не обойтись? Задание выдано на время стажировки

Comment: Зависит от вашего уровня. Есть вариант вообще писать на jquery+html+css. Ручной работы больше, поддерживать/дорабатывать тяжелее, но учить всего меньше.

Но вы просили готовое решение :)

Comment: В данном случае серверное решение не подходит.

Comment: Я прошу любую идею и благодарен услышанному) Но дальше уточняю в надежде выбрать для себя оптимальный вариант

Comment: jQuery - jQuery UI имеется ввиду?

Comment: jquery.ui уже дополнительно можете выучить. Но там не могу назвать какого-то модуля, который существенно поможет вам в решении данной задачи. Это ближе к набору ОТДЕЛЬНЫХ виджетов с возможностью настройки их взаимодействия на уровне перетаскиваний/кликов/простых события. Для single-page-app он все-таки простоват, более того может даже мешать.

Если нужны виджеты, лучше bootstrap. Там поскучнее с дизайнами, зато его проще встраивать в уже готовое приложение.

Comment: На какие элементы jQuery стоит обратить внимание?

Comment: События/эффективное обращение к элементам по селектору, в том числе область действия селектора (scope - второй параметр), привязывание данных к элементу и, ес-но, ajax. В базе этого должно хватить... Хотя это примерно 90% того, что используется в jquery:)